# Is there a way to see the sun's outer layers from earth outside a solar eclipse using polarization?

Tags: experimental-physics, astronomy, sun

¿Is there a way to filter sky light using light polarization?
in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronagraph#Invention it says:

High Altitude Observatory's Mark IV Coronagraph on top of Mauna Loa, use polarization to distinguish sky brightness from the image of the corona: both coronal light and sky brightness are scattered sunlight and have similar spectral properties, but the coronal light is Thomson-scattered at nearly a right angle and therefore undergoes scattering polarization, while the superimposed light from the sky near the Sun is scattered at only a glancing angle and hence remains nearly unpolarized.

¿How does it work?, i tried to watch to the day sky through a polarizing filter and i didn't see it much more dark.

Answer (score 0):

The [SOHO satellite](https://earth.esa.int/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/s/soho) uses polarization analysis to study direction of coronal magnetic fields. I guess this could also be done from Earth.

Comment: You might get a more detailed Answer on [Astromomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com).